# c#: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException (empity file)

Tags: c#

**Application:**
Industrial PC W7 Ultimate 64 bit

**Problem:**
We have often problem at power down ( cut off), look like this interruption corrupt file setting we use as follow:
**Properties.Settings.Default.**

When the application start again, show up following message:

**************** Exception Text **************

System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize --**

We use setting file for reload old value in the application grapich   (Windows chart framework 3.5)
Any idea Help? How to protect this writing / Reading process in system file
Are there any "FileClose" in order to protect sudden power down.

the file setting is the same:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <section name="WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false"/>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>



<appSettings>
    <add key="Ip_Box" value="192.168.214.241"/>
    <add key="Report_Box" value="Report"/>
    <add key="MaxValSp_Box" value="1000"/>
    <add key="NumSp_Box" value="10"/>       <!--Numero asse mand 1 es:10 x RPM -->
    <add key="NumDriveSp_Box" value="7"/>   <!--Indice n. Drive Sp1:CU[0],NX[1],NX[2],NX[3],CU_L1[4],..SP[7]-->
    <add key="NumSp2_Box" value="11"/>      <!--Numero asse mand 2 es:10 x RPM -->
    <add key="NumDriveSp2_Box" value="8"/>  <!--Indice n. Drive Sp2-->
    <add key="MaxValSp2_Box" value="10000"/>
    <add key="NumParRead_Box" value="33"/>  <!--R33 coppia attuale-->
    <add key="Language" value="ita"/>       <!--Language (ita-eng-deu  ecc...)-->
    <!--  HOME PAGE ******************************************************    -->
    <add key="Table1" value="1"/>           <!--1=On, 0=Off                   -->
    <add key="Table2" value="1"/>           <!--1=On, 0=Off                   -->
    <add key="Table3" value="0"/>           <!--1=On, 0=Off                   -->
    <add key="ActivateRef." value="1"/>     <!--1=On, 0=Off                   -->
    <!--  H.S.KEY  *******************************************************    -->
    <add key="Hsk3"   value="1"/>     <!--1=On, 0=Off                         -->
    <add key="Hsk4"   value="1"/>     <!--1=On, 0=Off                         -->
    <add key="Hsk5"   value="1"/>     <!--1=On, 0=Off                         -->
    <add key="Hsk6"   value="1"/>     <!--1=On, 0=Off                         -->
    <add key="Hsk7"   value="1"/>     <!--1=On, 0=Off                         -->
    <add key="Hsk8"   value="1"/>     <!--1=On, 0=Off                         -->
    <!--  TIRANTI  *******************************************************    -->
    <add key="adrDB" value="601"/>       <!-- DB tabella pressioni            -->
    <add key="adrDBW" value="80"/>       <!-- DBW iniziale tabella pressioni  -->
    <add key="adrDBWCnt" value="22960"/> <!-- Num tot  word db601 FCT DATI    -->
    <!--  HT8      *******************************************************    -->
    <add key="Ax1" value="X"/>
    <add key="Ax2" value="Y"/>
    <add key="Ax3" value="Z"/>
    <add key="Ax4" value="A"/>
    <add key="Ax5" value="W"/>
    <add key="Ax6" value="C"/>
    <add key="Ax7" value="W1"/>
    <add key="Ax8" value="W2"/>
    <add key="Ax9" value="W3"/>
    <add key="Ax10" value="B1"/>
    <add key="Ax11" value="B2"/>
    <add key="Ax12" value="B3"/>
    <add key="Ax13" value="SP"/>
    <add key="Ax14" value="A2"/>        <!-- DBX126.4=1  Ax4 Visual Ax14      -->
    <add key="Ax15" value="B2"/>        <!-- DBX126.4=1  Ax5 Visual Ax15      -->
    <add key="Ax16" value="C2"/>        <!-- DBX126.4=1  Ax6 Visual Ax16      -->


    <add key="Ax1Num" value="1"/>       <!-- 0=Off, 1,2..ordine Visualizz     -->
    <add key="Ax2Num" value="2"/>
    <add key="Ax3Num" value="3"/>
    <add key="Ax4Num" value="4"/>
    <add key="Ax5Num" value="5"/>
    <add key="Ax6Num" value="6"/>
    <add key="Ax7Num" value="7"/>
    <add key="Ax8Num" value="8"/>
    <add key="Ax9Num" value="9"/>
    <add key="Ax10Num" value="10"/>
    <add key="Ax11Num" value="11"/>
    <add key="Ax12Num" value="12"/>
    <add key="Ax13Num" value="13"/>
    <add key="Ax14Num" value="14"/>
    <add key="Ax15Num" value="15"/>
    <add key="Ax16Num" value="16"/>

    <add key="RefreshAxisTime" value="800"/>    <!-- Tempo refresh quote assi -->
    <add key="RefreshAxisPriority" value="2"/>  <!-- 0=Low - 1=Standard - 2=hight -->
    <!-- Tempo refresh quote assi -->
    <!--  Tab Pressioni ***************************************************** -->
    <add key="Cmp1"  value="Prs I° Tirante Montante AP16   "/>
    <add key="Cmp2"  value="Prs II° Tirante Montante AP17  "/>
    <add key="Cmp3"  value="Prs III° Tirante Montante AP18 "/>
    <add key="Cmp4"  value="Prs Controtiro In calcolata    "/>
    <add key="Cmp5"  value="Prs Controtiro Auto calcolata  "/>
    <add key="Cmp6"  value="Prs Controtiro totale calcolata"/>
    <add key="Cmp7"  value="Prs Tir Slitta Interno AP19    "/>
    <add key="Cmp8"  value="Prs Tir Slitta Est. Slitta AP9 "/>
    <add key="Cmp9"  value="Prs feedback Proporz.CT        "/>
    <add key="Cmp10" value="Prs feedback Proporz.TI        "/>
    <add key="Cmp11" value="Prs Pattino 25 IN73 Verticale  "/>
    <add key="Cmp12" value="Prs Pattino 26 IN74 Verticale  "/>
    <add key="Cmp13" value="Prs Pattino 54 IN75 Vertical   "/>
    <add key="Cmp14" value="Prs Pattino_55 IN76 Verticale  "/>
    <add key="Cmp15" value="Prs blc leggero TRT1           "/>
    <add key="Cmp16" value="Prs blc forte   TRT1           "/>
    <add key="Cmp17" value="Prs Meato 25 IN73 Vert.(calc.  "/>
    <add key="Cmp18" value="Prs Meato 26 IN74 Vert (calc)  "/>
    <add key="Cmp19" value="Prs Meato_54_IN75 Vert (calc)  "/>
    <add key="Cmp20" value="Prs Meato_55_IN76 Vert (calc)  "/>
    <add key="Cmp21" value="Prs blc leggero  TRT2          "/>
    <add key="Cmp22" value="Prs blc forte    TRT2          "/>

    <add key="Cmp1Num" value="1"/>    <!-- 0=Off, 1,2..ordine Visualizz     -->
    <add key="Cmp2Num" value="2"/>
    <add key="Cmp3Num" value="3"/>
    <add key="Cmp4Num" value="4"/>
    <add key="Cmp5Num" value="5"/>
    <add key="Cmp6Num" value="6"/>
    <add key="Cmp7Num" value="7"/>
    <add key="Cmp8Num" value="8"/>
    <add key="Cmp9Num" value="9"/>
    <add key="Cmp10Num" value="10"/>
    <add key="Cmp11Num" value="11"/>
    <add key="Cmp12Num" value="12"/>
    <add key="Cmp13Num" value="13"/>
    <add key="Cmp14Num" value="14"/>
    <add key="Cmp15Num" value="15"/>
    <add key="Cmp16Num" value="16"/>
    <add key="Cmp17Num" value="17"/>
    <add key="Cmp18Num" value="18"/>
    <add key="Cmp19Num" value="19"/>
    <add key="Cmp20Num" value="20"/>
    <add key="Cmp21Num" value="21"/>
    <add key="Cmp22Num" value="22"/>
    <!--  Tab Temp ***************************************************** -->
    <add key="Tmp1"  value="IN06 T.Ambiente                "/>
    <add key="Tmp2"  value="IN18 T.Mand Idrostatica        "/>
    <add key="Tmp3"  value="IN71 T.Mand Olio Cinematismi   "/>
    <add key="Tmp4"  value="IN72 T.Mand Frigo Cinematismi  "/>
    <add key="Tmp5"  value="IN70 T.Scarico Bussola di Raff "/>
    <add key="Tmp6"  value="IN21 T.I°Coppia Cuscinetti Ant "/> 
    <add key="Tmp7"  value="IN15 T.II°Coppia Cuscinetti Ant"/>
    <add key="Tmp8"  value="IN22 T.Copp.Cuscinetti Centrali"/>
    <add key="Tmp9"  value="IN11 T.Olio Raff. Bareno       "/>
    <add key="Tmp10" value="IN08 T.Testa(TUP*)/II°CorpoTTWM"/>
    <add key="Tmp11" value="IN69 T.Fl. Raffr. Motore MMand "/>
    <add key="Tmp12" value="IN68 T.Piastra Interfaccia Tes "/>
    <add key="Tmp13" value="IN99 T.Olio Mand.Idrost. Bareno"/>
    <add key="Tmp14" value="IN90 T.Cusc Ant.Irrigidit Baren"/>
    <add key="Tmp15" value="IN53 T.Int I° Corpo Testa/TTWM "/>
    <add key="Tmp16" value="IN18 Mandata Idrostatica TRT1  "/>
    <add key="Tmp17" value="IN18 Mandata Idrostatica TRT2  "/>

    <add key="Tmp1Num" value="1"/>   <!-- 0=Off, 1,2..ordine Visualizz     -->
    <add key="Tmp2Num" value="2"/>
    <add key="Tmp3Num" value="3"/>
    <add key="Tmp4Num" value="4"/>
    <add key="Tmp5Num" value="5"/>
    <add key="Tmp6Num" value="6"/>
    <add key="Tmp7Num" value="7"/>
    <add key="Tmp8Num" value="8"/>
    <add key="Tmp9Num" value="9"/>
    <add key="Tmp10Num" value="10"/>
    <add key="Tmp11Num" value="11"/>
    <add key="Tmp12Num" value="12"/>
    <add key="Tmp13Num" value="13"/>
    <add key="Tmp14Num" value="14"/>
    <add key="Tmp15Num" value="15"/>
    <add key="Tmp16Num" value="16"/>
    <add key="Tmp17Num" value="17"/>
    <!--  Grafico Temp ************************************************* -->
    <add key="NumSonde"   value="17"/>  <!-- Num sonde Visualizzabili     -->
    <add key="NomiSonde"  value="IN06;IN77;IN71;IN72;IN70;IN21;IN15;IN22;IN11;IN08;IN69;IN68;IN99;IN90;IN53;IN18;IN19"/>
    <add key="SogliaMinX" value="0"/>   <!-- Origine Base tempi    -->
    <add key="SogliaMaxX" value="600"/> <!-- MAX Base tempi        -->
    <add key="IntervalloX" value="60"/> <!-- Step Base tempi       -->
    <add key="SogliaMinY" value="20"/>
    <add key="SogliaMaxY" value="60"/>
    <add key="IntervalloY" value="2"/>
    <!-- 
    ********************************************************************************
                  Parametri inizializzazione Mag.Ute (LibNodave)
    ********************************************************************************
    -->
    <add key="Ip" value="192.168.214.1"/>           <!--Indirizzo IP CN          -->
    <add key="RefreshTime" value="1000"/>           <!--Tempo di Clock (refresh) -->
    <add key="TimeoutConnection" value="30000"/>    <!--Tempo di riconnesione    -->
    <add key="textNumPocket" value="100"/>          <!--Numero posti magazzino   -->
    <!-- 
    ********************************************************************************
    -->
    <!-- 
    ********************************************************************************
                              Pulsanti opzione Mag.Ute
    ********************************************************************************
    -->

    <add key="BalluffActive" value="0"/>    <!--0=Off - 1=On [Pulsante Balluff] -->

    <!-- 
    ********************************************************************************
    -->

  </appSettings>





 <userSettings>
        <WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="MachineTimeWorkTot" serializeAs="String">
                <value>00:00:00</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="MachineTimeManualTot" serializeAs="String">
                <value>00:00:00</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="MachineTimeStopTot" serializeAs="String">
                <value>00:00:00</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="MachineTimeWorkDay" serializeAs="String">
                <value>00:00:00</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="MachineTimeManualDay" serializeAs="String">
                <value>00:00:00</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="MachineTimeStopDay" serializeAs="String">
                <value>00:00:00</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="NumDay" serializeAs="String">
                <value />
            </setting>
            <setting name="ck1Green" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ck2Green" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ck3Green" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ck4Green" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ck5Green" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ck6Green" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ck7Green" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ck8Green" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ck9Green" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ck10Green" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ck11Green" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ck12Green" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ckMoGreen" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ckTuGreen" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ckWeGreen" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ckThGreen" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ckFrGreen" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ckSaGreen" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ckSuGreen" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="tbWeektimeGreen" serializeAs="String">
                <value>00:00</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="T1Green" serializeAs="String">
                <value>0</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="T2Green" serializeAs="String">
                <value>0</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="T3Green" serializeAs="String">
                <value>0</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="T4Green" serializeAs="String">
                <value>0</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="T5Green" serializeAs="String">
                <value>0</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="T6Green" serializeAs="String">
                <value>0</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="T7Green" serializeAs="String">
                <value>0</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="T8Green" serializeAs="String">
                <value>0</value>
            </setting>
        </WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>



 <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>

  <runtime>
    <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/>
  </runtime>
  <startup><supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup></configuration>
```

I save the configuration file in the timer.
I use this code for save: (example:     **Properties.Settings.Default.MachineTimeWorkTot = timeMachineWork.ActualVal; Properties.Settings.Default.Save()**)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you post the content of your config file ?

Comment: And i use Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); I use this in the timer and in the form.closed()

Comment: You should provide the complete stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general `ApplicationSettingsBase` does not handle power failure scenarios.

My first and most important suggestion is to deal with this scenario using an **UPS**. Take the pill and accept that whatever you do you won't have a 100% reliable software solution (at best the problem may be **mitigated** and corruption avoided with a well-designed software implementation and/or with file system support.)

Now I assume you went out to buy an UPS and you want to make your software more reliable. The things you have to do are these:

- Make a copy of your original unchanged configuration when program startups. It is proved to be correct and it can be used to restore configuration if required (changes from last run will be lost but at least you will still have *something*.)
- If configuration fails to load then restore from backup (if present) and try to load again.

Now if you keep using `ApplicationSettingsBase` then you may stop here. You may want to handle `ConfigurationLoading` event but it's just too *hacky* and I'd not feel to suggest it. Alternatively you can use custom `ConfigurationSection` and try to save your data in a little bit more reliable way:

1) Save your settings to a new file `Your App.exe.config.new`.

2) Make a copy of existing settings to `Your App.exe.config.bak`.

3) Replace `Your App.exe.config` with `Your App.exe.config.new`.

4) Optionally delete both `.bak` and `.new` files (unless you want to keep them for recovery...somehow).

Note that point 2, 3 and partially 4 are handled by `System.IO.File.Replace()` function. Do not try to re-implement it unless you're sure to make it correct and add some value.

---

All this said...you're saving application state inside configuration files. It's not, in my opinion, the right usage. They were not designed for this purpose. You may consider to use a better and more reliable storage for your state: **what about a local database**? It comes with built-in reliable I/O (better than what we may expect to do *by hand*. Not even to mention the other advantages (possibility to query values, intrinsically shared between processes, optionally journaled, easy to update/deploy/merge and so on...)

Comment: - We already use UPS , but it send a shutdown signal to pc and kill all application ( no application.exit its executed)

Comment: Then you should configure your UPS service to _gently_ close your applications (or, at least, to signal your critical ones that they're about to be killed). Alternatively (but I don't know what your UPS software actually does then I'm just guessing) you should take a look to `SystemEvents`, SessionEnd should be raised even if application will be forcefully killed

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer or Grazie mille if you are italian....- We already use UPS , but it send a shutdown signal to pc and kill all application ( no application.exit its executed) - Idea of backup a good file in a separate location we already do with app.config that are constant. We got informatin that  in order to have retenitive values use Setings file. Our issue is connected to sudden power off , we are looking for istruction let us protect, close this file after usage exemple: pippo.setting.default=value;    setting.default.save()  [maybe reset..referesh.. can help]

Comment: (prego, sì sono italiano) If you can't get better behavior from UPS software (you should check its documentation, it's unusual) then I'd go with backup file (at very beginning after configuration has been loaded, you will restore that if configuration loading fails). Better solution would be to create a backup file before you call Save(). However note that there are many caching layers and you do not have control over all of them (think if HDD is SDD drive...you'll get used to zeroed files)

Comment: Best thing to do (IMO!) is check get a shutdown notification (check SystemEvents class) to properly stop saving. This will minimize chances of corruption. Then put a backup strategy in place. Then...start moving application state to a proper storage (SQLCE? SQLExpress? LocalDB? MySQL? there are many options...pick the one that best suits to your scenario) Refreshing/resetting won't help you much (IMO) because it will still hit the software cache (at SO or HDD level)

Comment: Thanks (grazie).I try this ;-) if I capture the shutdown notification and close the application with application.exit(). In the event form_closed(), use setting.default.saving() and after the application close. In the end, pc shutdown with ups. do you think it might work?

Comment: Yes, it should be. You may also want to save only if something changed (check PropertyChanged event) and also save _compacting_ few changes together.

Comment: Ok...I try this...Thanks a lot....Before I write the used solution...;-)

Comment: What is the difference between form_Closed() and form_Closing()? I write setting.default.save() in first or in the second form event? thanks

Comment: Closing happens first and BEFORE form has been closed. Closed happens later and after form has been closed. However the most important difference is that Closing event may be canceled (eventually canceling close action and/or delaying shutdown until Windows decides to brute force kill your application)

Answer (score 0):

```
                            **WORKAROUND WITH EXTERNAL SIGNAL**
```

Good Morning at all...for the moment we solve by workaround:

- Catch UPS signal (Working on Battery) by PLC bit and share this information with pc;
- Put UPS information in the timer and if is true stop the timer and make **Application.Exit()**;
- Move setting backup in Form_Closed() event, make **Setting.default.save()** and **base.dispose(true)** for "clean memory".

I tried to catch the computer shutdown event but it was complicate.
This solution is powerfull but the better solution is used pc shutdown event instead of UPS bit.

Thanks at all